# Query for an item inside of Fields - DSL Query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I read on this article [elasticsearch query](https://logz.io/blog/elasticsearch-queries/) and [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) to be able to query for `ElasticApmTraceId` that has a specific ID throughout my entire logs.

[image]

So I attempted to do the following just to get `ElasticApmTraceID`:

```
GET /customer-simulation-es-app-logs*/_search
{
 "query": { 
   "match": {
     "fields": {
       "ElasticApmTraceId": "da58115e800c284b8e2556185c1c8e64"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

However, when I do so, it returns:

[image]

**Is there a reason why it returns a 400 and not what I want it to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the structure of the document, the `ElasticApmTraceId` field is inside `fields`. You can access the values of `ElasticApmTraceId` by using `fields.ElasticApmTraceId`

Modify your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "fields.ElasticApmTraceId": "da58115e800c284b8e2556185c1c8e64"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `bool`,`must`and `term` to query.The following article should help you: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

```
GET /customer-simulation-es-app-logs*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "ElasticApmTraceId": {
              "value": "da58115e800c284b8e2556185c1c8e64"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So always use bool and must and term for every DSL query?

Comment: You can read the article in my link.These constructors are just to construct your query conditions.Please classify according to the actual situation :）

Comment: I appreciate it :)